# To prove the divergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

let $f$ be a real, decreasing function. Define the sequence $\{a_n\}$ as $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}= a_n + f(a_n)$ and prove that it tends to infinity.

I can see that the general term $a_n= 1+ \sum  f^{n-1}(1)$ and I am trying to prove this sum is divergent, but I can't see how.

Comment: this is not true for $f(x) = 1-x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shall assume $a_0=0$ and $f:\>{\Bbb R}_{\geq0}\to{\Bbb R}_{>0}$. The sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ is then strictly increasing and has a limit $\alpha=\sup_n a_n\leq\infty$.

Assume that $\alpha<\infty$, and let $f(\alpha)=c>0$. There is an $a_n>\alpha-c$, and as $f$ is decreasing we have $f(a_n)\geq c$. This implies
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+f(a_n)>\alpha-c+c=\alpha\ ,$$
a contradiction.